# Bootstrap datetimepicker with left & right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want bootstrap datetimepicker like below image,

[image]

Where, on left arrow click it will change previous day's date and with next arrow it will show next day's date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example or show what you have tried. read  [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have just added bootstrap datepicker. What i want is when user click on left arrow, date field should change with previous day's date and same with right arrow for next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using jquery date picker with bootstrap design. If I am not wrong, since you haven't provided any source code. 
If you are using jquery's date picker, you can adjust the next and prev date easily:

HTML

```
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

The Jquery code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

$("#prev").click(function(){
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate', '-1d'); 
    date.setDate(date.getDate()-1); 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
})


$("#next").click(function(){
        var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
})
```

JSFIDDLE 
https://jsfiddle.net/noitse/r1s0bwm6/